# How to successfully Rewrite a URL with .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rss, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite mysite.com/broadcasts to mysite.com/feed so that it will show up in the location bar as "broadcasts" but actually go to /feed.

Here is what I have in the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^broadcasts(/)?$ /feed/ 
</IfModule>
```

But this isn't working... I get a 404 error.

Wondering if I'm doing something stupidly wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you do it:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/broadcasts$ $1/feed/
```

This will make sure no matter what domain you use, it will always be matched if you have the right combination, making it easier if in the future you decide to change domains for example.

**UPDATE**
I accidentally used (.*) twice on my example, but it has been fixed

Hope this helps you

Comment: domain is not passed in URI in mod_rewrite

Comment: But this makes sure whatever is before it, is matched.

Comment: for url mysite.com/broadcasts your (.*) will always equals to empty string. so for constant url it's ambiguous.

Comment: Yes, but if for instance he decides to create a parent folder, it will come in handy, and is already future proof

Comment: And the $1 means that whatever was before the /feed/ will be before the /broadcasts/ eh?

Comment: Hmm... I've tried both ways and they are not working... might it be because I am using Wordpress? And it has its own rewrities as well? I put this one before them in the .htaccess file though...

Comment: Is it still 404'ing then? Weird, coz this should work wherever it's placed.

Answer (score 0):

remove trailing / from /feeds/ ;-)

at least - this works for me right now

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
RewriteRule ^broadcasts feed
```

in your .htaccess file.
If it doesn't work, try add

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
```

in the top of your file.